# Ubuntu 13.10 - Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init

Tags: boot, grub2

After installing an update I restarted my computer. Ubuntu failed to boot, so I used boot-repair to try to fix it. After running boot-repair grub2 was removed and the Ubuntu os was no longer detected by the live cd. I reinstalled grub2 which worked, but I got the error:

```
mount: mounting on /dev on root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting on /sys on root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting on /proc on root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg
```

After this, it brings me to busy box. I found solutions for the error. fsck and e2fsck don't work.

Boot summary here: http://pastebin.com/5CeCMQjx ubuntu is installed in sda1.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

I was really concerned about this error behavior as well. I was without Internet and Ubuntu Live CD so I had to try the following procedure which successfully solved the current error.

This procedure is applied on the following failure characteristic as well:  `Serious errors were found while checking the disk for /`. So I used following procedure as proposed in [Solve serious error /](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218439):

1. During booting up on Ubuntu hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down so you will enter into the "Advanced Boot Options" for Ubuntu.
2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit GRUB2 boot entry.
3. You need to change the GRUB2 boot entry from "ro" to "rw"

=> Instead of mounting as read-only, mount for read-write

4. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot
5. After booting change the crub.cfg file in terminal

   `gksudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

so the changes you made in the boot options will be saved permanently.

Find the lines:

```
linux    /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=[bunch-of-numbers] loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro rootflags=sync  quiet splash
```

6. As you did in the grub menu change "ro" to "rw", => Instead of mounting as read-only, mount for read-write

It worked in my case, for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as well. I hope it does for your case as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might still be able to boot into your Ubuntu installation using Super Grub2 Disk. Basically it scans your partitions for grub2 and windows bootloaders then in your ram it generates an new grub2 boot manager with entries for any operating systems it detects so you can boot into them. The disc doesn't make any changes to your system.

Step #1 = Download Super Grub2 Disk, burn it to an dvd/cd, and boot it up.

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/

Step #2 = See if it detects your Ubuntu installation with the default option, if not try the other grub2 related entries, and then boot Ubuntu.

Step #3 = Run boot repair again, remove Super Grub2 Disk, and reboot into Ubuntu.