# Error after updating to ubuntu 16.04.1 from 14.04.1 "Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init" (please read before marking as duplicate)

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, updates, init

There are many people talking about this error and I have tried all the solutions that I saw but none of them worked for me. I am searching for a solution for hours and asking here is my last attempt to fix it, before formating the partition and reinstalling ubuntu.

I was using my ubuntu and saw a pop-up asking if I wanted to update to 16.04.1 LTS. I agreed and after a long period of time, my computer logged off by itself and when I logged in again, the installation was interrupted and I got some screens saying the update couldn't be completed. But the attempt to update ubuntu already had deleted several packages I had (for example my terminal was not true color anymore), then I restarted and got the error bellow:

[image: my error screen]

My init file isn't in /sbin anymore. I searched for a lot of proposed solutions to this (with many people commenting it had worked for them) but none of those worked for me. I tried:

1. I got a bootable pendriver with ubuntu 14.04 .iso and booted from it, used `fsck /dev/sda6`, `fsck -f /dev/sda6` and `e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda6`, following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17647/target-filesystem-doesnt-have-requested-sbin-init) and [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1788381).
2. I copied my /sbin directory to my /home so I can restore it later, deleted my ubuntu's /sbin and copied my bootable pendriver's /sbin to my ubuntu root folder. I tried this with 14.04, 14.04.4 and 16.04.1 bootable pendrivers, following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727810/target-filesystem-doesnt-have-requested-sbin-init-bin-sh-0-cant-open-spl).
3. I tried going into GRUB screen, pressing <kbd>e</kbd> and changing the 'ro' to 'rw' and boot it (with <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl+x</kbd>) with my original sbin in it, following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442146/ubuntu-13-10-target-filesystem-doesnt-have-sbin-init).
4. I tried mounting my partition and using `chroot` to perform `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, which took something like half an hour, following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure).

Like I said, nothing worked. This is a comparison of my original /sbin (on top) to my 14.04.1 LTS bootable pendriver`s /sbin:
[image: my /sbin on top]

EDIT: I just gave up, formated my partition and installed ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Comment: To help with diagnosing this it would help to have more information can you please add your /etc/fstab file. It would also help to check if there are any additional boot errors before the kernel panic such as mounting errors, to see them you may need to temporarily disable quiet boot and the splash screen, to do so follow the steps in this guide https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters and delete the words quiet and splash from the line starting with the word linux. If any other errors appear please do add them to your question to help diagnosing.

Comment: @MttJocy, my fstab:

UUID=4713326a-7e9c-4d8c-957b-845bfb4e6ea6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile   none    swap    sw    0   0

Comment: I have the same problem. Did anyone find a working solution for this, other than formating and reinstalling ?